# How accurate are principle component analysis (PCA) algorithms?

Tags: statistics

Biologists and other researchers widely use PCA to analyze experimental data. I was under the impression that it was a settled science, until I came across this article [[1](https://doi.org/10.1111/rssb.12301)].

In particular, it says "The first step, choosing the number of components, remains a serious challenge."

The article continues to saying that the current method is widely accepted because it "works well in practice", but it isn't well understood why. This article sheds some light on that.

My question is: how accurate current PCA algorithms are? How likely is that they miss real principle components every once in a while?

#### References

1. Edgar Dobriban; Art B. Owen Deterministic parallel analysis: an improved method for selecting factors and principal components. *Royal Statistical Society/Statistical Methodology/Series B* **2018**, 81 (1), 163-183. https://doi.org/10.1111/rssb.12301.

Comment: I don't know what you mean how accurate? PCA finds the dominant dimensions in an orthonormal eigensystem for the covariances in your data.

Comment: Does it find all dominant dimensions? Can it miss some? If it would say that there are 5 principle components in the 65-dimensional data set, and the other 60 components are random, how likely it is that it didn't miss the 6th statistically significant component? In case of a high-dimensional data it must be not trivial to find them.

Comment: You're fundamentally misunderstanding how PCA works. It doesn't "say" there are 5 principal components. It gives you 65 components that are ordered by the magnitude of the singular values. The biologists/practitioners *choose* to disregard the other 60 on the hypothesis that the first 5 are the most dominant and this choice is arbitrary. They could just as easily choose to keep the first 6 or the first 7 etc. This is not a mathematical issue, mathematically you keep all 65. It's like choosing to keep a certain number of decimal places, mathematically you should keep all of them.

Comment: Maybe the right question is "Can an algorithm reliably find principle components in NxM array, when N is dimensionality, and M is the number of subjects." Because this is what this article, and the ones that it cites (by Horn and Louis Guttman) talk about.

Comment: It is not sure that it is the covariance over linear combinations like that which carries the information you are looking for in your application. I suppose you mean something like : "how good is PCA as a method for my application"? I have no idea if it is the right tool to use.

Comment: In general, there is the NxM data array of potentially correlated data. The hypothesis is that this data can be described by a limited number of variables k<<min(N,M), and a function f(x_1, ..., x_k) -> DataPoint such that it would capture a statistically significant correlation, and the rest would be noise. Can statistics answer the question of finding k and f() given the data?